# friendly_id and real id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

Is there any way to get the real `id` column from a model that is modified with friendly_id?

I don`t want to make another db query for it, in performance reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Broadly speaking friendly_id modifies `to_param` and `find` methods. Next should work:

```
@affiche = Affiche.find(params[:id]) # params[:id] is a slug
@id = @affiche.id
```

Comment: That\`s clear, thank you. But I wish I could avoid another db query

Comment: Where is another db query here?

Comment: Oh, I didn\`t get it first time, I\`m sorry. That is the answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `attributes["id"]`? e.g: `Model.first.attributes["id"]`

Comment: I don\`t really get where to use it. But if I'll do in controller `@id = Affiche.first.attributes["id"]` I get nothing

Comment: Do you get `nil`? if the database query triggered by running `first` includes the `id` column i think you should be able to access it via the attributes hash. But i don't know how the friendly_id plugin works, looks like it uses a separate table for all slugs. So i guess @voldy answer should work.

Comment: but again it is one more query, isn't there another way? Something like modifying model, maybe, to add the real `id` to `params`. Or somehow pasing the real `id` through the slug? And slugs are in the same table as `id`s for `frienly_url`

Comment: I meant that you should be able to use `attributes` on the model instance you already have. How do you look up the model instance in the first place when using the friendly id?